# Make duplicate html document with autogenerated name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Essetially, I am building a very rudimentary website builder that uses forms on a page to manipulate the HTML of the page,displayed below the input boxes, which eventually the user can get the source of to put onto their own website. I have not built it yet, but I was thinking that I would need more than one template in case anyone was trying to edit the same template at the same time, and having their edits overridden by others using the program. Here is a mockup for your leisure:

Html Displayed below input:

```
<h1 class="heading">Hi guys!</hi>
```

Form mockup:

```
<input id="headingEdit">
<script>
document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = document.getElementById("headingEdit").value;
</script>
```

My problem is one that may or may not be relevant, and that is that should someone want to edit this template, when someone else is also editing it, then surely the html would keep on getting overridden by each other, and no-one would get anywhere. What I therefore want to do is be able to, when a user clicks on the 'Edit this Template' button on the homepage, they are taken to a randomly generated page, which is an exact duplicate of a master page, make their edits, and then that page is deleted, or (when I add integration) stored in a users account.

This might be a duplicate question, but the answer has not come up in my research so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to have look at the open source [Silex](http://www.silex.me/) web page editor for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `AngularJS`

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">
 
<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short PHP solution

```
$pageid = uniqid();
copy('template.html', $pageid . '.html');

print "Editable page is at: " .$pageid . ".html";
```

Add this somewhere in the `template.html`:

```
<?php
    if (str_replace(' ', '', preg_replace('/\.html/', '', basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))) !== 'template') {
        print "<script>
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    i;
for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
elems[i].setAttribute('contentEditable', 'true');
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
    var a = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        a.onreadystatechange = function (b) { 
            if(a.readyState==4&&a.status==200){
            } 
        }

       xmlhttp.open('POST','remove_template.php',true);
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
       xmlhttp.send('id=" . str_replace(' ', '', preg_replace('/\.html/', '', basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))) . "');
} 

//Custom JavaScript goes here
</script>";
    }
?>
```

Then `remove_template.php` is:

```
if ($_POST['id'] != 'template' && ctype_alnum($_POST['id'])) {
    unset($_POST['id']);
}
```

You should obviously change what urls to your needs, also `remove_template.php` is *kinda* insecure. I haven't tested this yet. If you ever add a user system. Made the `$pageid` link to their user account. Then just pass an if to not add the `window.onbreforeunload`

Comment: Ok, thanks, am testing this one now, but might use your js if I can't get this one to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't support PHP you can use an icky JavaScript solution

```
window.editPage () { document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on'; }

window.savePage () { localStorage.setItem('savedPage', document.body.innerHTML); }

window.getPage () { document.body.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('savedPage'); }
```

Then you can add the function to the `onclick` attribute

```
<div onclick="window.editPage()">Edit Page</div>
```

---

I've found something called [Surreal CMS *(Content Management System)*](http://www.surrealcms.com) which might be what you want. Or maybe something like [create.js](http://createjs.org/demo/hallo/)